# MixIn is not applied for json deserialization of scalar value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a [YearWeek](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) from threetenextra library from a json scalar string using jackson with the following mix in:

```
import org.threeten.extra.YearWeek;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

public class YearWeekMixIn {
    @JsonCreator
    public static YearWeek parse(String value) {
        return YearWeek.parse(value);
    }
}
```

But the following test fails:

```
public class YearWeekMixInTest {

    public record Foo(YearWeek yearWeek) {}
    
    @Test
    public void foo() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(YearWeek.class, YearWeekMixIn.class);
        
        objectMapper.readValue("{\"yearWeek\": \"2011-W01\"}", Foo.class);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.threeten.extra.YearWeek` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2011-W01')

What is missing in the mix in to let jackson know it should use the annotated method in the mixin for deserialization?

Comment: As per open issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1820, doesn't look like what you expect is supported yet. Solution 2 provided by `smileis2333` looks like a reasonable alternative

Comment: @devatherock But per comment https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1820#issuecomment-388517251 in that issue: "Just to make sure: mix-in annotations can already be attached to static factory methods without problems." - does this just mean `@JsonCreator` is considered a mixin annotation and attaching here only means attaching it to  static factories within the acutal class in question?

Comment: Just realized that this use case is different than the one mentioned in the open issue - adding a `@JsonCreator` annotation to a static factory method that already exists vs providing a brand new factory method. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MixIns are used to inject annotations into methods that already exist in the class being mixed into, not to provide new implementations and not to provide custom factory methods. The signature of the mixed in method needs to match exactly with the method in the actual class. In this case, the signatures don't match as the `parse` method in `YearWeek` class accepts a `CharSequence` whereas the MixIn's `parse` method accepts a `String`. Matching the method signatures would make this work. The MixIn class could look something like the below:

```java
import org.threeten.extra.YearWeek;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

public abstract class YearWeekMixIn {
    @JsonCreator
    public static YearWeek parse(CharSequence value) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson's mixin doesn't support add outside factory method.
So I think I have three other solutions for you.

https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue/ maybe be help you understand the key point

the doc's key is the 3.
as if the ''target class'' had all annotations that the ''mix-in'' class has (for purposes of configuring serialization / deserialization)
in the mixin, it associate the annotations(it's not as the entry as identifier), it like aspect-oriented, but actutally it isn't aspect-oriented ehence, it just attach extra meta data to the target class

solution1(kept all method signature consistent)

```
    class YearWeekMixIn {

        @JsonCreator
        public static YearWeek parse(CharSequence text) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

solution2(using StdConverter, and there is no need to config ObjectMapper)

```
class YearWeekConverter extends StdConverter<String, YearWeek> {
    @Override
    public YearWeek convert(String s) {
        return YearWeek.parse(s);
    }
}

record Foo(@JsonDeserialize(converter = YearWeekConverter.class) YearWeek yearWeek) {}
```

solution3(using StdDeserializer)

```
class YearWeekDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<YearWeek> {

    public YearWeekDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public YearWeekDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public YearWeek deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final String s = jp.readValueAs(String.class);
        return YearWeek.parse(s);
    }
}

public class YearWeekMixInTest {

    public record Foo(YearWeek yearWeek) {}
    
    @Test
    public void foo() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(YearWeek.class, YearWeekMixIn.class);

        // add module
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(YearWeek.class, new YearWeekDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        objectMapper.readValue("{\"yearWeek\": \"2011-W01\"}", Foo.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations#usage-notes states that "All annotation sets that Jackson recognizes (core annotations, JAXB extensions) can be mixed in". So I would count `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator` as one of those.

Comment: If it can be tolerated, you could kept the method's signature consistent, I added the solution to the answer

Comment: I just realized that you were actually first with proposing the correct solution. I probably didn't notice earlier since it was an edit. But since the system only lets me now create a bounty with at least 200 rep you will need to take this as soon as the system lets me. Hope you don't mind ;)